# Extracting values from ComboBox in JavaFX and passing it to an SQL Query in a different class

Tags: mysql, javafx-2

I have two classes.One class produces a PIE chart with values that are retrieved from a MySql database.We fire an SQL query for this. I  also have a  GUI with combo Boxes.I wish to extract the value from the combo boxes and then embed these Extracted values into the SQL query .

For eg. In the GUY if the user selects year as 2012 from the combo box and category as roleband from a different combo box i need these values to be put in an sql statemnt at run time .
Is this possible please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`comboBox.getValue();` will give the current value set for the combobox ,if you want to execute query when ever combobox value changed then add a Listener to it .